# sends from exacttarget and getting tracking in CRM : microsoft dynamics 2011 and Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

WE have a suituation :

1. we sent the email to subscibers from CRM.

2.we get the tracking report back to CRM and the Exacttarget responses doesn't contain First open date / first click date somehow.

1. We want to re-send the emails to those who did not opened the emails.

4.But from the CRM we can't do as we dont have information.

5.So as a round about solution , can we do the following:

a. From Exacttarget tracking information/details of that particular send , we copy

subscriber of 'Did not open' to a new subsciber lists and make a guided sends / sends .

b. Just wonder if we can get the tracking information back to CRM when we do sends from Exacttarget directly or atleast the unsubscribes ??

c. Any other way to do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When MSCRM initiates the sending, it keeps a record to "sync" with ET.  If you send from ET directly, MSCRM will have no way of knowing it.  So the tracking/unsub info you're looking for won't be there automatically.

There may be a way to export the data and later import it into MSCRM.  I'm sure you can do the  export; you can use a DataExtract and export a data extension.  I have no idea how you would import it on the MSCRM side.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As you said the only way is to export from ET and import to MSCRM. But in my scenario, i only get GUID,Emailaddress from the ''Did not open' subscriber lists from ET.So, planned to have a custom appl which takes import file and fetch those corresponding contacts in to a static marketing lists.